# Dynamic raw query (select clause) Django

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to execute a raw query in Django where I dynamically want to pick column names.
Eg

```
   def func(all=True){
   if all:
      query_parameters = {
           'col': '*'
      }
   else:
      query_parameters = {
           'col': 'a,b,c'
      }
    with connections["redshift"].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "select %(col)s from table limit 2 ;",
            query_parameters,
        )
        val = dictfetchall(cursor)
        return val
    }
```

Django is executing it like.

`select "*" from table limit 2;`

so the output is just like `select "*"`

`*`

and in the else case it is executed like

`select "a,b,c" from table limit 2;`

so the output is `a,b,c`

How can I run the command so that Django run it like

`select a , b , c from table limit 2`

so that the output is

```
a b c 
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack myself.
[See Here](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/dynamic-raw-query-select-clause-django/13017/13)

Explanation

Prepared query step by step

Input data (Columns I need)

self.export_col = “a,b,c”

```
def calc_col(self):
        if self.exp == 'T':
            select_col = ""
            self.export_col = self.export_col.split(',')
            for col in self.export_col:
                select_col += col + ","
            select_col = select_col[:-1]
            self.export_col = select_col
        else:
            self.export_col += '*'

def prepare_query(self):
        query += " SELECT "
        query += self.export_col
        query += """ from table limit 2;"""
```